# I want to make a server which can take video as a byte stream and save it

Tags: java

I want to make a server which can take video as a byte stream and save it.i got the stream and write the file in .mp4 file but it does not play because it is corrupted.

```
int port = 3332;

ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
System.out.println("waiting for connection on port "+port);

Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
System.out.println("connection stablished on port "+port);

String clientIPAddress=socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
System.out.println("client ip address\t"+clientIPAddress);

in = socket.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bstream=new BufferedInputStream(in);
DataInputStream dstream=new DataInputStream(bstream);
out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);


try{
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D://output/Output.mpeg");

    while(isDisconnect){
        String deviceId=dstream.readLine();
        System.out.println(""+deviceId);

        String timeStamp=dstream.readLine();
        System.out.println(""+timeStamp);

        while ((length = bstream.read(theServer.buf)) > 0) {
            fos.write(theServer.buf, 0, length);
            System.out.println("Length\t"+length+"\n");
            out.println("received");

        }   
    }       
} catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(""+timeStamp);` nitpick, but `"" + ...` is useless.

Comment: `FileOutputStream("D://output/Output.mpeg");` != mp4?

Comment: @skynet i tried for .mp4 also but same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try following code for saving stream into a file without corrupt, let me know if any other help required or I missed something

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils;



 public class Test1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4");
            inputStream = url.openStream();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("/Users/dev/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG_copy.mp4"));
            byte[] byteArr = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            outputStream.write(byteArr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    // outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: will that happen ?

Comment: in my earlier code file was written and it's size also in MB's but when i'm open it in VLC  or other media player it doesn't play

Comment: can you explain why you're using `fos.write(theServer.buf, 0, length);` instead of  fos.write(theServer.buf);

Comment: fos.write(theServer.buf,0,length) in this method buf values are writes in the FileOutputStream from 0 index upto the length value

Comment: i'm able to read one file and write it on other location but i'm struggling to write the live stream of video which are coming in byte stream

Comment: try updated code sample, if you still facing any issue please let me know

Comment: if its work then click on right sign and up for a vote

Comment: i did that but i didn't have required reputation for upvote